# What is the best way to sort a string, considering the last characters as numbers, in excel vba

Tags: excel, string, vba, sorting

I have an array which has string values, and I would like to know the best way to sort it, but I need to consider the last characters as numbers.

Here is one example:
If I have the values IRF2BP2K10, IRF2BP2K1 and IRF2BP2K2 as the 1st, 2nd and 3rd elements inside my array, how can I sort them so my array can be arranged as {IRF2BP2K1, IRF2BP2K2, IRF2BP2K10} instead of {IRF2BP2K1, IRF2BP2K10, IRF2BP2K2}?

I have tried the basic code below, but I end up with the second case, where IRF2BP2K10 is sorted before IRF2BP2K2, as the algorithm only considers the strings:

```
For currentitem = 1 To lastitem

    For nextitem = currentitem + 1 To lastitem

        If Array(currentitem) > Array(nextitem) Then

            Temp = Array(currentitem)
            Array(currentitem) = Array(nextitem)
            Array(nextitem) = Temp

        End If

    Next nextitem

Next currentitem
```

Some people asked me, so here is more information: not all items end with a "K" before the number.

Here are some other values for the example, I didn't write them as in a array, so it can be easier to visualize:

```
(this list is the result using my code)
IRF2BP2KICMVCRE1
IRF2BP2KICMVCRE10
IRF2BP2KICMVCRE2
IRF2BP2KIERT2CRE1
IRF2BP2KIERT2CRE10
IRF2BP2KIERT2CRE11
IRF2BP2KIERT2CRE2
IRF2BP2KO1
IRF2BP2KO2


this is what i was trying to get:
IRF2BP2KICMVCRE1
IRF2BP2KICMVCRE2
IRF2BP2KICMVCRE10
IRF2BP2KIERT2CRE1
IRF2BP2KIERT2CRE2
IRF2BP2KIERT2CRE10
IRF2BP2KIERT2CRE11
IRF2BP2KO1
IRF2BP2KO2
```

Do I need an algorithm to compare every string position of the array's "currentitem" with the same position of the array's "nextitem"? And, if all of them are equal, put the item that has the bigger length after the one with the smaller length? [this way I could sort IRF2BP2K2 in a position before IRF2BP2K10, as both of them share the same initial strings "IRF2BP2K", and differ only on the last strings (one has "2" and the other has "10")]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: will there always be just a single or two digit number at the end?

Comment: No, but the maximum may be something around 4 digits. I don't know if you would suggest that, but I don't want to put zeroes before the last number (for example, IRF2BP2K1 would have to be transformed to IRF2BP2K0001).

Comment: They can be, but as they are in the middle of the string, it won't matter for me, they can be sorted as string characters. The problem is that I want an algorithm to compare the last strings, if they are numbers, and order them as numbers, not "letters".

Comment: Then consider the solution of @user3598756 below and tweak it a bit, i.e. find the last non-number letter and format (temporarily) the number with fixed length.

Answer (score 1):

**edited** `GetFormattedArray()` function to "properly" format the array elements last digits

i think you must first *format* your array elements properly and then do the sorting

for instance you could use the following function to return a *properly formatted* array

```
Function GetFormattedArray(originalArray() As String)
    ReDim formattedArray(LBound(originalArray) To UBound(originalArray)) As String
    ReDim ipos(LBound(originalArray) To UBound(originalArray)) As Long
    Dim ielem As Long, iChar As Long, maxChar As Long
    Dim strng As String
    Const zeros As String = "0000000000"


    For ielem = LBound(originalArray) To UBound(originalArray)
        strng = originalArray(ielem)
        iChar = 1
        Do While IsNumeric(Mid(strng, Len(strng) - iChar, 1))
            iChar = iChar + 1
        Loop
        ipos(ielem) = iChar
        If iChar > maxChar Then maxChar = iChar
    Next


    For ielem = LBound(originalArray) To UBound(originalArray)
        strng = originalArray(ielem)
        formattedArray(ielem) = Left(strng, Len(strng) - ipos(ielem)) & Format(Right(strng, ipos(ielem)), Left(zeros, maxChar))
    Next

    GetFormattedArray = formattedArray
End Function
```

that your "main" could exploit as follows:

```
Sub main()
    Dim myArray(1 To 3) As String, myFormattedArray() As String
    Dim currentItem As Long, nextItem As Long, lastItem As Long
    Dim tempStrng As String

    myArray(1) = "IRF2BP2K10"
    myArray(2) = "IRF2BP2K1"
    myArray(3) = "IRF2BP2K2"

    myFormattedArray = GetFormattedArray(myArray)

    lastItem = UBound(myFormattedArray)
    For currentItem = LBound(myArray) To lastItem

        For nextItem = currentItem + 1 To lastItem

            If myFormattedArray(currentItem) > myFormattedArray(nextItem) Then

                tempStrng = myFormattedArray(currentItem)
                myFormattedArray(currentItem) = myFormattedArray(nextItem)
                myFormattedArray(nextItem) = tempStrng

            End If

        Next nextItem
    Next currentItem

End Sub
```

Comment: In my case that was just an example. Not all values will end with a "K", it can be any letter

Comment: AFAICS this should be the simplest solution. @muntukli you can modify it to catch the first non-numeric letter from the end instead of just finding "k".

Comment: @muntukli, did you get through it?

Answer (score 0):

Just use your bubblesort with your own custom comparator function.  I'm not exactly clear on what values you need to support (this example assumes that the first 8 characters are compared as strings and everything after that is compared as a number):

```
Public Function CodeGreaterThan(first As String, second As String) As Boolean
    If Left$(first, 8) > Left$(second, 8) Then
        GreaterThan = True
    ElseIf Left$(second, 8) > Left$(first, 8) Then
        GreaterThan = False
    Else
        GreaterThan = Val(Right(first, Len(first) - 8)) > _
                      Val(Right(second, Len(second) - 8))
    End If
End Function
```

Then use that instead of `>`:

```
For currentitem = 1 To lastitem
    For nextitem = currentitem + 1 To lastitem
        If CodeGreaterThan(arr(currentitem), arr(nextitem)) Then  '<--
            temp = Array(currentitem)
            arr(currentitem) = Array(nextitem)
            arr(nextitem) = temp
        End If
    Next nextitem
Next currentitem
```

Answer (score 0):

If you data number on the right only includes up to four digits, I would try using LCase and UCase to identify the numbers at the end and then sort it based on that:

```
Dim CurrentStg, NextStg As String

For currentitem = 1 To lastitem

For nextitem = currentitem + 1 To lastitem

If LCase(Right(Array(currentitem), 4)) = UCase(Right(Array(currentitem)), 4) Then
CurrentStg = Right(Array(currentitem), 4)
Exit For
ElseIf LCase(Right(Array(currentitem), 3)) = UCase(Right(Array(currentitem)), 3) Then
CurrentStg = Right(Array(currentitem), 3)
Exit For
ElseIf LCase(Right(Array(currentitem), 2)) = UCase(Right(Array(currentitem)), 2) Then
CurrentStg = Right(Array(currentitem), 2)
Exit For
ElseIf LCase(Right(Array(currentitem), 1)) = UCase(Right(Array(currentitem)), 1) Then
CurrentStg = Right(Array(currentitem), 1)
End If

If LCase(Right(Array(nextitem), 4)) = UCase(Right(Array(nextitem)), 4) Then
NextStg = Right(Array(nextitem), 4)
Exit For
ElseIf LCase(Right(Array(nextitem), 3)) = UCase(Right(Array(nextitem)), 3) Then
NextStg = Right(Array(nextitem), 3)
Exit For
ElseIf LCase(Right(Array(nextitem), 2)) = UCase(Right(Array(nextitem)), 2) Then
NextStg = Right(Array(nextitem), 2)
Exit For
ElseIf LCase(Right(Array(nextitem), 1)) = UCase(Right(Array(nextitem)), 1) Then
NextStg = Right(Array(nextitem), 1)
End If

    If CurrentStg > NextStg Then

        Temp = Array(currentitem)
        Array(currentitem) = Array(nextitem)
        Array(nextitem) = Temp

    End If

Next nextitem

Next currentitem
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the below example:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim a()
    Dim r()

    a = Array("IRF2BP2KICMVCRE1", "IRF2BP2KICMVCRE10", "IRF2BP2KICMVCRE2", "IRF2BP2KIERT2CRE1", "IRF2BP2KIERT2CRE10", "IRF2BP2KIERT2CRE11", "IRF2BP2KIERT2CRE2", "IRF2BP2KO1", "IRF2BP2KO2")
    Range("A1").Resize(UBound(a) + 1, 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(a)
    r = SortByLastDigits(a)
    Range("B1").Resize(UBound(r) + 1, 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(r)

End Sub

Function SortByLastDigits(Data()) As Variant()

    Const adVarChar = 200
    Const adDouble = 5

    Dim RegEx As Object
    Dim List As Object
    Dim Elem
    Dim q()
    Dim r()
    Dim n As Long

    Set RegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    RegEx.Pattern = "(.*?)(\d*)$"
    Set List = CreateObject("ADOR.Recordset")
    List.Fields.Append "e", adVarChar, 255
    List.Fields.Append "t", adVarChar, 255
    List.Fields.Append "n", adDouble
    List.Open
    For Each Elem In Data
        With RegEx.Execute(Elem).Item(0)
            List.AddNew
            List("e") = Elem
            List("t") = .SubMatches(0)
            List("n") = CLng(.SubMatches(1))
            List.Update
        End With
    Next
    List.Sort = "t, n"
    List.MoveFirst
    q = List.GetRows
    ReDim r(UBound(q, 2))
    For n = 0 To UBound(q, 2)
        r(n) = q(0, n)
    Next
    SortByLastDigits = r

End Function
```

The output for me is as follows (initial array in column `A`, sorted in column `B`):

[image: output]